# How to forward declare templated type that should belong to a class?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Assume I have 2 classes:

```
class A
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ref;
  ...

private:
  B::Ref _b;
}

class B
{
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<B> Ref;
  ...

private:
  A::Ref _a;
}
```

This obviously requires forward declaration of class B and B::Ref. Forward declaring B is simple, but how to do that for B::Ref too?

Comment: The way to solve this on design level might be to introduce the third class, that would know about the other two.

Comment: Even if you could forward declare `B::Ref`, that wouldn't be enough for you because you need the definition to have a member of that type.

Comment: Not a duplicate, because the question is not about a simple typedef forward declaration. The templated variant is significantly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't forward declare a nested `typedef` since at the point of the forward declaration `B` would be an incomplete type. You can however solve your problem like below:

```
class B;

class A {
  std::shared_ptr<B> _b;
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ref;
};

class B {
  A::Ref _a;
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<B> Ref;
};
```

Comment: That actually I liked most because it only requires a single change (instead of "B:Ref _b" we use "std::shared_ptr<B> _b". Everything else stays at it is. Small and beautiful.

Answer (score 8):

One of way to solve this is

```
class A;
class B ;

template <typename T>
struct Traits {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T>  Ptr; 
};


class A
{
    private:
      Traits<B>::Ptr _b;
};

class B
{
    private:
      Traits<A>::Ptr _a;
};
```

Comment: I think it should be `typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Ptr;` ?

Answer (score 2):

Having a typedef for "this is how you refer to objects `X`" inside class `X` is a bad design decision, precisely because you need the full definition of `X` to see its members, but you want to be able to refer to `X` without its full definition.

I can see two ways of solving this. One is to abandon scoping and simply call the typedef `RefA`, defined where the class is forward-declared:

```
class A;
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> RefA;
```

Alternatively, you can delegate the "knows how to refer" to a separate class. You could make it a class template, so that classes can still register their own preferred referring types there:

```
template <class T>
struct RefT
{
  typedef T *type;  // Default reference type
};

template <class T>
using Ref = typename RefT<T>::type;


class A;
template <>
struct RefT<A>
{
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> type;
};


class B
{
private:
  Ref<A> _a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot forward declare nested typedef. However, you could just use global typedefs, like

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<B> RefB ;
```

and so on. Other solution is to use late template specialization, sth like the following:

```
template <typename T> class BImpl;

template <typename T>
class AImpl
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<AImpl> Ref;
private:
    typename BImpl<T>::Ref _b;
};

template <typename T>
class BImpl
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BImpl> Ref;
    typename AImpl<T>::Ref _a;
};

typedef AImpl<void> A;
typedef BImpl<void> B;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I feel like forwarding a typedef, I always consider inheritance. It could look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Ref : public std::shared_ptr<T>
{
    Ref()
    {}
    Ref(T *t)
        : std::shared_ptr<T>(t)
    {}
};

class B;

class A
{
public:
    //...

private:
    Ref<B> _b;
};

class B
{
public:
    //...

private:
    Ref<A> _a;
};
```

Comment: This will be next to impossible to use unless you inherit the constructors of `std::shared_ptr` as well.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for the hint. Now this answer is more like "If you *really* want to dodge typedef ...". Otherwise I'd find P0W's answer more appealing.